# Create directories based on names in txt file with added strings

Tags: powershell

Teacher here, total powershell newb, trying to save a little time creating student folders for assignment submissions.

I have the following to make a new folder for every line (student name) in the text file.

```
$folder="X:\9-3_Science";
$txtFile="X:\9-3_Science\9-3_StudentNames.txt";

get-content $txtFile | %{

    if($_)
    {
        mkdir "$folder\$_";
    }
}
```

Which outputs folder such as \FirstLast

However, I'd like to output folder names with a concatenated string to identify which classroom the student resides in, such as \9-4_FirstLast_Science

How do I modify the "mkdir" command to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed the following:

- you want to have the students folders inside the classroom folder
- the Students are all on a seperate line in the `.txt`

If that is all true, we can do the following:

- Get the leaf of the `$folder` and split it on `_` to get the `RoomNumber` and the `Subject` for further use
- Create a string by combining `$folder`, `Room ($split[0])`, `StudentName ($_)`, `subject ($split[1])`
- use that string to create a folder.

That results in the following code:

```
$folder = "X:\9-3_Science"
$txtFile = "X:\9-3_Science\9-3_StudentNames.txt"

$Number = "9-3_"
$Subject = "_Science"

Get-Content $txtFile | ? { $_ -ne '' } | % {
    $FolderString = "{0}{1}{2}" -f $Number, $_, $Subject
    $FolderName = Join-Path $folder $FolderString
    mkdir $FolderName
}
```

What I changed from your code:

- PowerShell does not require an ending `;` after each line, so I removed them.
- instead of `if ($_)` i filtered empty lines before the loop already with `? { $_ -ne '' }`

Comment: Thanks so much for the changes, SimonS!

However, no need for this assumption:

"- the name of the source folder is always <RoomNumber>_<subject>"

If you could show me how to simply manually append and prefix their names for the directory name that would allow me to be a bit more flexible. 

Something like this which I know is totally incorrect:

 $FolderName = "9-3_" -f $folder, + "_Science"

Comment: @mikeauer I changed the code according to your comment. Whatever you write in `$Number` will now be the prefix and `$Subject` will be added after the students name

Comment: You are an absolute gem of a human being!!

Comment: @mikeauer well thank you, you can also be a gem of a human being, by clicking the check mark symbol next to my answer to mark this question solved :-).